# Find mixed indentation whitespace

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write regex to match mixed indentation (i.e. tabs and spaces).

Here is what I have currently:

```
.*((\t )|( \t))\s*
```

Results:

(`--->` stands for tabs, dots for spaces).

```
....--->....foo    matched
--->....--->foo    matched
--->....foo        matched
....--->foo        matched
```

The problem is that it matches mixed whitespace in the middle of the line. I want to get rid of this matching, i.e. I want to match indentation only:

```
....foo....--->....bar    should not be matched
```

Comment: What those dots that `->`s mean?

Comment: To match spaces or tabs form the start of the string, try `^[ \t]+`

Comment: @revo `--->` mean tab. I have added it to my post.

Comment: There would be some other ways for this but if lookaheads are supported I'll go with this one `^(?=\s*\t)\s* \s*` or probably `^(?= *\t)\t* \s*`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Doesn't properly work. https://regexr.com/4eo9d

Comment: Are you trying to match trailing whitespaces of each line? or they should be a mixture of tabs and spaces?

Comment: @revo Yes, they are supported and your regex works correctly, thanks. It could be an answer. (However it would be even nicer to have 2nd regex without lookaheads).

Comment: `^\s*(\t | \t)\s*` or `^(\t+ | +\t)\s*`

Comment: The link you provided doesn't have tabs but you expect it to be a match?

Comment: @trincot Thanks! Slightly changed it: `^\s*(\t | \t)\s*` and `^(\t+ | +\t)\s*`. And now it works as I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in comments, the most important feature you were missing is the start-of-string anchor (`^`) and you should not use `.*` as that will also match non-white space, which you want to avoid.

You can get the match with either `^\s*(\t | \t)\s*` or `^(\t+ | +\t)\s*`. The second one would be more efficient.

Depending on your environment, you may need to add a `m` modifier (or equivalent) so that `^` matches with the start of a line (instead of the start of the whole input).

Comment: on your second option, you don't really need the trailing   \s*   do you?

Comment: @Richard, You do need it, for instance to match tab+space+space

Comment: \s* means  zero or more whitespace characters, and you have nothing following it in the regex, nor an end anchor ($).  
So, once you've matched the (\t+ | +\t)  literally anything (including "nothing") matches.

Comment: Yes removing it will still give a match, but the OP's purpose is to include those extra spaces in the match.

Comment: good point.  fyi, I upvoted you even before my first comment :-)